# URL Rewrite - Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, url-rewriting

I followed a tutorial to create pretty URLs for my site that I plan to host on Google App Engine (Python).

The problem is it won't display the index pages inside subdictories.

I have a file called abc.html which loads fine at this address
http://www.testsite.com/abc

But I have index files in subdirectories (xyz and 123) which won't load into the content area (blank spacing in content area)

Subdirectory xyz with index.html:
http://www.testsite.com/xyz

Subdirectory 123 with index.html  inside directory xyz:
http://www.testsite.com/xyz/123

Here is the code I used

**app.yaml**

```
application: testsite
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

default_expiration: "1d"

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|xml))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|xml))

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

**main.py**

```
import os
    from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
   def get(self, p):
      if p:
         page = p + ".html"
      else:
         p = "main"
         page = p + ".html"

          if not os.path.exists(page):
         page = "404.html"

      template_values = {
            "page" : page,
                p: "first", 
      };

      path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
      self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([(r'/(.*)', MainPage)],debug=True)

def main():
   run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>TestTitle</title>
   <link href="/static/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
   <div id="header">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="main">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="abc">abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="xyz/123">xyz</a></li>
            </ul>
   </div>

   <div id="content">
      <!-- this is where content will be loaded -->

      {% if page %}
         {% include page %}
      {% else %}
         {% include "main.html" %}
      {% endif %}

   </div>

   <div id="sidebar">
      TestSideBar
   </div>

   <div id="footer">
      TestFooter
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: The tutorial I followed was a dynamic page + URL rewrite guide. The dynamic page aspect is not really necessary. I just couldn't find a tutorial that would get pretty URLs working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all either your app.yaml or your main.py is erroneous.
Since Python27 is the more modern runtime, I suggest it's app.yaml
I suggest the following app.yaml:

```
application: testsite
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.application
```

Then you talk about files called index.html inside subdirectories, but they are accessed nowhere. Instead, you access 'xyz.html' and 'xyz/123.html'.

Try the following code snipped instead:

```
        if p:
            page = os.path.join(p, "index.html")
        else:
            p = "main"
            page = "main.html"
```

By the way: You should consider template inheritance instead of the include tags!